# Any alternatives to using Iframe or methods to get my current one functioning?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, connected-apps, iframe

This is the Visualforce page that I have being displayed.

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" standardController="account">
<apex:form >
    <apex:detail id="OrganisationDetails" title="false" inlineEdit="true"/>
</apex:form>
```

I am showing it on an object called "Apprentice" which is a related object done by displaying it as an Iframe like so-

```
<apex:page applyHtmlTag="true" title="Organisation Details" standardController="Apprentice__c">
  <apex:repeat value="{!Apprentice__c.employer__r}" var="organisation">
    <iframe scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" height="2300px" id="Hybrid_Organisation_Details" name="Hybrid_Organisation_Details" src="Hybrid_Organisation_Details?id={!organisation.Id}" width="100%"></iframe>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

[image]
This works super effectively and works as intended by showing details from related objects, but when any links or buttons are pressed from within the Iframe I receive this issue.
[image]
Basically im wondering if a workaround is available to get an iframe where all the buttons and links function. I have heard the word Heroku floating about & connected apps but I have no clue how to use that or even get started.

I'm not sure if Apex:includes will work because I cant use it in an Apex:repeat tag. Therefor I cant used the function src="Hybrid_Organisation_Details?id={!organisation.Id}" that determines the related record.

Comment: Have you tried to use visualforce component instead of iframe?

Comment: No I haven't, how would I go about trying that?

Comment: What's the reasoning behind this approach you're attempting rather than using the related list component to display the related Employer details?

Comment: To try and use the Classic details layout with the Lightning functionality. Sort of like a hybrid design, but i'm not sure if its possible.