# How do I use Salesforce Canvas to function like an Iframe?

Tags: visualforce, canvas, iframe, heroku

Any guides to help me get started with Canvas in Salesforce? 
Need to use it for an Iframe replacement and the guides I have read feel like they skip a big section of how to use it.

Comment: Your question is going to be difficult to answer with resources that will help you without knowing more information about where you need guidance. What is the 'big section' that you believe they miss describing effectively?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257865/any-alternatives-to-using-iframe-or-methods-to-get-my-current-one-functioning?noredirect=1#comment390926_257865 Im trying to find an alternative way of doing this but to no avail. And this is what i tried following https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/quick_start_create_canvas_app.htm I got to stage 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way us to go step by step through this documentation 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/quick_start_simple_create_app.htm

In short :
on your heroku app you need to implement code that will act on POST request to your controller and get Signed Request decrypted.

You need to use decrypted signed request to organize interaction between Salesforce and external app via browser side JS. - Canvas App is not a good solution to iframe internal org pages.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257865/any-alternatives-to-using-iframe-or-methods-to-get-my-current-one-functioning?noredirect=1#comment390926_257865 Im trying to find an alternative way of doing this but to no avail. What would you recommend as opposed to Canvas?

Comment: Why don't you put this details in Visualforce Component and then use apex:repeat?